# Deleting certain character from right and left of a string in vb6 (TrimChar)

Tags: string, vb6

I want to delete some certain characters that used wrongly in a string.

"........I.wanna.delete.only.the.dots.outside.of.this.text..............."

as you can see I can't use replace for this. I must find a way to delete only the characters at left and right of a string and those dots only an example of characters that I want to delete. I have an array of those unwanted characters. So after the process string should look like

"I.wanna.delete.only.the.dots.outside.of.this.text"

but I couldn't find a way to get this work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

VB6 has a `Trim()` function but that only removes spaces.

To remove characters from both ends, you'll need to check each end in turn removing the character until you get something else:

```
Function TrimChar(ByVal Text As String, ByVal Characters As String) As String
  'Trim the right
  Do While Right(Text, 1) Like "[" & Characters & "]"
    Text = Left(Text, Len(Text) - 1)
  Loop

  'Trim the left
  Do While Left(Text, 1) Like "[" & Characters & "]"
    Text = Mid(Text, 2)
  Loop

  'Return the result
  TrimChar = Text
End Function
```

Result:

```
?TrimChar("........I.wanna.delete.only.the.dots.outside.of.this.text...............", ".")
I.wanna.delete.only.the.dots.outside.of.this.text
```

This is far from optimised but you could expand on it to just work out the end positions, then do a single `Mid()` call.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Public Function Remove(text As String) As String

      text = Replace(text, "..", "")

      If Left(text, 1) = "." Then
         text = Right(text, Len(text) - 1)
      End If

      If Right(text, 1) = "." Then
         text = Left(text, Len(text) - 1)
      End If

      Remove = text

    End Function
```

If you remove any instances of ".." then you may or may not be left with a single leading dot and a single trailing dot to deal with. If you are lucky enough to be able to guarantee that the dots will always be an even number then

```
 text = Replace(text, "..", "")
```

is all you need.

Comment: And how do you get `Replace()` to differentiate the . you want to keep and the . you don't? They can't replace the entire "keep" part of the string until they know what it is (which is what they're asking)

Comment: Hmm, yes. I assumed (wrongly?) that the string he wanted to keep was a constant.

Comment: Edited my answer to provide a working answer. Different approach to @Deanna.

Comment: +1 for simplicity
with the help of @Deanna i made it with a longer way.

actually ill post that example too as an answer but yea your answer is simple and solves the problem totaly. thank you.

Comment: This clobbers any .. in the middle of the string :|
`.....What about this.... It's no longer what they wanted :|...."

Comment: It is wrong based on your question. Whether you're happy with that design or not is up to you.