# Visual Basic | White Spaces | Tab Spaces | How Can I remove the white spaces?

Tags: vb.net

I am coding with Visual Basic. I want to remove the white spaces like tab spaces from a string line.

I have already tried the methods on the internet like Replace(), Trim(), Left(), Right(). None of them work for me. What else I can do ?

```
    Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(dosya, FileMode.Open)
    Dim sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(fs)
    Dim fs1 As FileStream = New FileStream(dosya1, FileMode.Append)
    Dim sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fs1)

    Do

        satir = sr.ReadLine
        satir = satir.Replace(vbTab, " ")
        satir = satir.Replace(" ", " ")
```

Comment: check you data for invisible special characters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trim all types of whitespace, including tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25184019/trim-all-types-of-whitespace-including-tabs)

Comment: Does `satir = Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(satir, "\s+", " ").Trim()` give the result you are looking for?

Comment: In what way do they "not work"? That's kind of vague. Trim gets rid of leading and trailing whitespaces... are you looking for more than that? Is the problem whitespace between words? Are you looking to replace multiple spaces/tabs between words? It's that kind of info that's helpful. General statements like "it doesn't work" is like walking into the doctor's office and saying "it hurts.," Bah! No one does that. It's usually something like "I was skating and I fell and hurt my arm and think it's broken."

Comment: If it's tabs and multiple spaces between words you want to replace, start by replacing all tabs with spaces, then keep replacing all double spaces with single spaces until there are no more double spaces left.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ and the method [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=netframework-4.8)

```
satir = String.Concat(satir.Where(Function(c) Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c)))
```

Comment: Be aware that this will also remove hard returns as well as all spaces and tabs.